# CSS nested lists width and height

Tags: css, footer, nested-lists

I am trying to get a footer menu styled in CSS using nested lists, since that seems the standard way nowadays most CMSes work with. However I am having a hell of a hard time getting the width and height dynamically expanding to the right sizes. So each top level list item is positioned horizontally, while each child level list item is then listed underneath.

**Problem 1:** I want the total width of the top level list item to be the width of either the longest child list item or the top list item, whichever is longer. I don't want breaking lines.

**Problem 2:** The height of the surrounding DIVs is not expanding (tried using both `overflow: auto` and also the `clear: both` approach with the `:after` CSS selector) and scrollbars are displaying instead.

I want to avoid fixing heights because I want to make the menus dynamic.

What do I have to do to solve the above issues? This is what I have so far: ([live example](http://jsfiddle.net/TLRSC/))

```
   <div id="footer">
    <div id="footerstrip" >
        <div id="footercontent" >
            <div id="footerleft">
                <img src="images/LogoGrey.png"  />&nbsp;<a href="#"><img src="images/FooterHome.png" /></a>
            </div>

            <div id="footer-menu-div">
                <ul id="footer-menu">
                   <li>Fashion
                       <ul>
                        <li>Apparel</li>
                        <li>Celebrity Styles</li>
                        <li>Fashion Spotlight</li>
                        <li>Trends</li>
                       </ul>
                   </li>

                   <li>Beauty
                       <ul>
                        <li>Hair</li>
                        <li>Skincare</li>
                        <li>Make-up &amp; Cosmetics</li>
                        <li>Nails</li>
                       </ul>
                   </li>

                   </li>
                   <li>Lifestyle</li>
                   <li>Love</li>
                   <li>Culture</li>
                   <li>Subscribe</li>
                   <li>Events</li> 
                 </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS:

```
#footer 
{
    margin-top: 30px;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}

#footerstrip
{
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#footercontent
{
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    width: 1100px;
    text-align: left;   
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #e0e0df;
}

#footercontent a
{
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;   
    text-decoration:none;
    overflow: auto;
}

#footercontent img
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#footerleft
{
    text-align:right; 
    width: 120px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    margin: 0px; 
    float: left;    
}

#footer-menu-div
{   
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

#footer-menu-div:after {
    content:"";
    clear:both;
    display:block;
}

ul#footer-menu
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;   
}

ul#footer-menu li
{
    background-color: #c7c6c6;
    color: #212121;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    float: left;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    position: relative;
}

ul#footer-menu li:first-child
{
    border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;     
}

ul#footer-menu li:last-child
{
    border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;        
}

ul#footer-menu li ul 
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;     
}

ul#footer-menu li ul li
{
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: inline;    
}
```

**UPDATE**

I only want that strip with the rounded corners to be around the top level list items, not around all the items. So it will be around one line all horizontally.

**UPDATE 2**

In actual fact, the contents of each list item will be an `<a>` link.
Based on the feedback so far, I managed to come up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TLRSC/9/), however I had to do the `<a>` with `width: 100%` in order for the background to continue with the next top level item, and due to this its going out of horizontal space. :(

If there is a way to make the top level item links be as wide as the longest of the child links the issue would be solved.

Comment: Let me put that in a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/TLRSC/

Answer (score 1):

I think both problems should be solved by getting rid of `ul#footer-menu li ul { position: absolute; }`. This immediately solves the scrolling problem but we still need the list items to display one per line. So, add this: `ul#footer-menu li ul li { display: block; float: none; }​`.

Now the only remaining problem is the background being inconsistent. I think you will need to 
put the background on the `<ul>` like so: `ul#footer-menu { overflow: hidden; background-color: #C7C6C6; border-radius: 5px; }`. Then you can remove `background-color` and `border-radius` from the `<li>` elements.

Here's the finished product in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TLRSC/6/

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there any way the background with the rounded corners goes only around the top level items? That is the whole point really of what I am trying to achieve. Thanks again!

Comment: btw, the reason for those positions was because I was trying to use the same approach we use for drop down menus, where we style the top level list items independently from the children.

Answer (score 0):

OK after lots of trial and error, I managed to get it to look the way I wanted.
The rounded background is associated with the anchors of the top level list elements, rather than the list elements themselves. I had to play around with `float : left` and `clear: left` settings of both the surrounding `div`, both `ul` tags, the `li` tags and the `a` tags to get it to work (honestly no idea which combination did the trick exactly).

But anyway here it is working:

http://jsfiddle.net/TLRSC/11/