# CSS horizontal float widths and links going beyond their parent width

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to do a footer which can seamlessly integrate with most CMSes, so it uses list items and nested lists within them, menu style. The design I received has the top level lists with a continuous grey background, while the nested list items just sit underneath them with no background.

After lots of fiddling with float and clear settings I managed to come up with this (live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/mQqWX/).

This is very close to what I need. The problem is that to have the continuous top (darker) grey background I had to make the links have 100% width. This is causing the anchor's widths to go outside the `li` items that host them, and when I do `overflow: auto` on the `li` items, I just get scrollbars instead of expanding to the anchor's width.

This is causing the problem on the far right, where the last item in the list (Events) is having the rounded background go beyond the boundary of the containing `div` and `ul` into the 'About Us' link (which should not have the background). Again trying `overflow: auto` just gives me scrollbars. I also have the clearfix (with :after) on both elements.

How can I make the link's width just the width of their containing `<li>` so that I don't have that overflow on the right which I am getting with `width: 100%`?

How can I make the wrapper `<div>` and `<ul>` expand to contain the width horizontally, without getting those nasty scrollbars?

Thanks!

P.S. This is a continuation of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326663/css-nested-lists-width-and-height) with some progress made after lots of trial and error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `box-sizing: border-box` to the `a`'s. That solves it. It doesn't work in older IE's though. To make it work you could add a `span` inside the `a` tag. The `a` tag would have the 100% width set on it, the `span`, with `display: block`, would have the padding.

The problem comes from the fact that the padding gets added to the `width`. `width: 100%;` + `padding: 20px;` makes `width` actually equal to `100% + 20px + 20px`. It's more than what you want.

`box-sizing: border-box;` tells the browser to keep the `width` always at 100% - padding + border + width = 100% - this is what I use these days - I add it to all elements via the universal `*` selector.

Comment: Thanks for that! It actually does not work in Firefox too, but adding -moz-box-sizing: border-box; solves it for Firefox too. Will do some tests with IE to see how far back it works.

Comment: No problem. Yes you still need the prefix. Didn't but should have mentioned it, ya ;)

Comment: Yes, I actually included all 4 alternatives I know of:-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;

Answer (score 2):

Remember : Padding + Width = true displayed width

so if you set width:100% and padding-left:10px
Lets say the parent has a with of 500px
the true displayed width will be 510px, which enables the scroll bar, its miss-leading but its css

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. JOPLOmacedo however gave me the solution, but +1 for you too.

Comment: No problem, this was more informational than an answer anyhow :) This is an easy point to overlook

Comment: Yes it always happens to me... I get these kinds of weird problems and do not realise its because the padding still adds up extra to the width, although we do 100% to expand the full width of the container... unintuitive CSS as you said :(